# Create a two line text file without anything written to stdout

Tags: bash, stdout

So basically I want to write a two line file containing this:

```
This is line one
This is line two
```

I can easily do this by doing this command in bash:

```
echo "This is line one\nThis is line two" > filename
```

But how would I do this without writing it to stdout.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your slash is going the wrong way, and `echo` by default wouldn't interpret `\n` as a new line.  Beyond that, what is going to `stdout`?  You mean you want to do it without redirection operators?  If so I'd probably use an editor like `vi` or whatever is your preference

Comment: Stderr?? Not clear.

Comment: Just fixed the slash, didn't realize it. Basically the " > filename" that going to stdout.

Comment: strange question.... I would creater perl/python/whatever script which saves lines to file. but better try to explain your requirements

Comment: Stdout is standard output

Answer (score 4):

In `ksh`/`zsh`

```
print -u3 "This is line one\nThis is line two" 3> filename
```

would do it using a different file descriptor than 1/stdout if that's what you're asking.

Or you could do:

```
dd of=filename <<EOF
This is line one
This is line two
EOF
```

Or:

```
sed -n 'w filename' <<EOF
This is line one
This is line two
EOF
```